# Infinitive with "zu" after modal verb?

Tags: grammar, infinitive

In an exercise, they ask to translate

> I like to sleep in my bed

which I'd translate as

> Ich mag in meinem Bett schlafen

However according to them my translation is wrong, and they give

> Ich mag es in meinem Bett zu schlafen

which however I don't understand. Questions:

- is my version also correct?
- is their version correct?
- is there some difference in meaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both versions are correct. It depends on context.

For example:

> In which bed do you want to sleep next night?
>
> I'd like to sleep in my bed.

This would be translated as

> Ich möchte in meinem Bett schlafen.

or if you like

> Ich mag in meinem Bett schlafen.

But if the context is:

> What do you enjoy doing?
>
> I like to sleep in my bed.

is translated as:

> Ich mag[or liebe] es in meinem Bett zu schlafen.

or even simpler:

> Ich schlafe gerne in meinem Bett.

Comment: Thanks, so I interpret the alternate form something like _Ich mag es, in meinem Bett zu schlafen_ ie _I like it, to sleep in my bed_ (although I suppose it can't really be translated that way).

Comment: @karoshi So to speak. But you wouldn't say it in English like that. I guess the difference in English is inserting *would* what is possible in German, too. "Ich würde gerne in meinem Bett schlafen". At any rate, the comma is wrong.

Comment: It should be noted that while "mögen" *can* take an infinitive, it almost never does in contemporary usage. Much, much more often it takes a noun: "Ich mag Erdbeereis" or a subclause: "Ich mag es, wenn du mich streichelst" (and the second form requires the 'es'). Therefore, the canonical translation is definitely "Ich schlafe gern...".

Comment: @Em1 Yes, I was only inserting the comma to emphasize how **I** was logically breaking down the sentence, without implying that it should be used in the real language (although see Kilian's answer...)

Comment: I think we should add, that mögen + infinitive is in colloquial a bit childish German used without es... "Ich mag Musik hören, schlafen, auf Party gehen". It could be argued that those are actually nouns but I think most people would write it wthout capital which hints at a perception as a verb.

Comment: I'd also note that in both languages there's a different connotation depending on how the emphasize is put: "I like to *sleep* in my bed" ("Ich *schlafe* gern in meinem Bett"), "I like to sleep in *my* bed" ("Ich schlafe gern in *meinem (eigenen)* Bett", "I like sleeping in my bed" ("Ich mag es, in meinem Bett zu schlafen").

Comment: What is the purpose of "es" in the correct answer the OP wrote in his question? Ich mag es in meinem Bett zu schlafen